# Multiple elements (4) matching error when trying to use XML in Robot Framework

Tags: xml, selenium, robotframework

Getting error while trying to find the child elements of my xml input data, how to solve this?

Error - Multiple elements (4) matching './/Operations' found

My code - @{child_xml}=   XML.Get Child Elements      ${path_to_Login_xml}    .//Operations

XML Data:

```
<AutomationTestModel>
        <OrderNumber>111111</OrderNumber>
        <Product>4444</Product>
        <ShipQty>1</ShipQty>
           <Operations>
              <Operations>
                 <Name>Test</Name>
                 <Org>Testing</Org>
              </Operations>
              <Operations>
                 "some more data"
              </Operations>
              <Operations>
                 "some more data"
              </Operations>
           </Operations>
    </AutomationTestModel>
```

Comment: There are several `<Operations>` elements, which is what the error is telling you. Which one do you want to get?

Comment: I want the child elements of first Operations.